# NoReverseMatch at /projects/ Reverse for 'user-profile' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am just getting started with Django and I don´t know exactly where this error comes form. It´s probably related to the owner attribute. Here is my code so far.

projects/modely.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

users/models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

projects/views.py

```
def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'projects':projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```

projects.html

```
{% for project in projects %}
<p><a class="project__author" href="{% url 'user-profile' project.owner.name %}">{{project.owner.name}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

users/views.py

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'users/user-profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you allow the name field to be blank and null, thus when you ask for it in the url of your `<a href>` it is sending in an empty string, yet your `userProfile` view is asking for a `pk`.

First, remove the null and blank from your classes:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Second, require users to login before they enter, otherwise you will still have blank strings for the `project.owner`, which will lead to the same result.  You can do this with the [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'projects':projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```

Then in your html:

```html
<a class="project__author" href="{% url 'user-profile' project.owner.user.pk %}">
```

But finally, the [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453443/17562044)
answer by [@Snow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12758446/snow) is correct.  The [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) model already has a username, first_name, last_name field, so you might be able to get rid of the name field in the Profile model, then do just:

```html
<a class="project__author" href="{% url 'user-profile' request.user.pk %}">
```

Comment: Here is a part of the urls.py:  `path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name="user-profile"),`    If i do it as you kindly said I am getting follwing error message when clicking on the link:  DoesNotExist at /profile/230d5590-d90a-4697-beb7-b1f5415a690f/
Profile matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The [User object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects), already has fields for basic information like the `username`, `password`, `email` and `first` and `last` name.

You're creating a new field called name to do URL lookups, but have set your field name to `blank=True`. You can't lookup a profile without having a `slug` (in your case the profile name). So instead, you should lookup the user by the username. Always try to stick to the DRY approach (don't reinvent the wheel).

Try doing this:

```
<a class="project__author" href="{% url 'user-profile' project.owner.user.username %}">
```

if you have an [app_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) in your urls, then you need to use the app name.

```
<a class="project__author" href="{% url '<app_name>:user-profile' project.owner.user.username %}">
```